# Angular - how to check if next value of a callback is a specific one, and do something in case is not?

Tags: angular

I'll simplify my code and show you an example:

I have this array of objects:

```
let myArray = [{month: 1}, {month: 2}, {month: 4}, {month: 6}];
```

I have a function used to map the values of this object, to another object:

my mapping function:

```
mapFunction(myObj) {
return {newProperty: myObj.month}
}
```

then I Call this function inside a `map()` :

```
let myNewArray = this.myArray.map(mapFunction);
```

and this works great, it maps each value of `myArray` using my function.

Now I want to add an extra step,
if the next iteration of my map() is not a sequential month, it must add an object with the missing month value.

So with the above example, it should add 2 new objects, `{month: 3}, {month: 5}`
because they are missing, but it should not add the months after the last one, only those that create "holes"

I hope I made myself clear.

My mapping function should check if the next `month` value equals to the `previous + 1`
but we need also to consider that there might be bigger gaps, like 2 missing months in a row, and it should fill them both!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking your requirements as stated, you want to fill in the gaps in an ordered, non-sequential array.

One way of performing a complex map is to use the `reduce` array function.

You could pad out your original array and then pass that into your mapping function:

```
months = [];

ngOnInit() {
  let myArray = [      
    {month: 20},
    {month: 3}, 
    {month: 4}, 
    {month: 6}
  ];

  myArray = myArray
    .sort((a, b) => a.month - b.month)
    .reduce((arr, current, idx) => {
      const month = current.month;      

      if (idx > 0) {
        const previous = myArray[idx - 1].month + 1;
        for (let i = previous; i < current.month; i++) {
          arr.push({month: i});    
        }   
      }

      arr.push(current);
      return arr;
    }, []);            

  this.months = myArray.map(this.mapFunction);
}

mapFunction(myObj) {
  return {newProperty: myObj.month}
}
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hsgdqt

Comment: thank you for the answer, first of all, I simplified everything, all this mapping happens inside a big reduce() function, and the object has 10properties and not only "month". That's why I need to preserve my mapFunction, because it maps all the properties of that object, and my idea was inside the mapFunction(), to put the check, and if the object with the following correct month is missing, then map to a new object that has that missing month, and put to null all other properties

Comment: Map will map an n-dimension array to another n-dimension array. You need something else in there.

Comment: So you could make a "filled-in" version of your original array, and then pass it through your existing function?

Comment: I see, didn't think about this, and it won't be a problem if I put another reduce() inside my bigger reduce? I will try your way, basically with that reduce() you are using, I'm mapping the existing objects to my new interface, and pushing new objects that I created for the missing month in the final array?

Comment: you could also chain the reduce to your map. i.e. `array.map().reduce()`. to preserve your mapping, but then also do the check based on the new array format.

Comment: that is a great idea, I could quickly check the length, and push X empty objects in my array, before mapping, but then, I have a sort function in place as you did in your example, this would push all the empty objects at the end, then it would be enough to sort again after the mapping right? could you provide then an example for my existing mapping function, knowing it will have always 12objects for 12months

Comment: @AJ989 I've updated my answer. That's definitely a cleaner approach and keeps the concerns separate

Comment: @KurtHamilton ok so based on your last updated answer, I should use reduce() as soon as I get my "months" array from my observable, use it to fill with empty months, then finally pass my map function which will map that array to a new array of a different type! Seems all clear, going to try it now

Comment: @KurtHamilton I'm having an issue, if the first month is not 1, but maybe 3, it will create months for value 1 and value 2, how can I change the code to start the count only from the first month value in the array?

Comment: @AJ989 Ah, I put that in as an assumption (never assume!). I've updated my answer.

Comment: damn I hate myself, I made a big mistake, your solution works, but as I told before, the object doesn't only have 1 property, but multiple, and there is a value that I cannot set null, but must come from the DB for that month (each month has a specific value). So I will change the backend, and send all months always, they will have a property called: show: boolean, if false, that month is a "missing" month, so if will only be shown if it creates a hole, but if not, it will be ignored! So how can I change your function, that instead of (finishing on next message, no char left)

Comment: that instead of checking what "months" are missing, it checks on every object, the new property "show", and if false, it must check if removing that month would create a hole, if not, remove it

Comment: I will make another question with the new issue, so we keep this good solution you answered

Comment: The solution will depend on how strict your requirements are, but it should be fairly simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can create add new items into array using simple loop:

```js
let myArray = [{month: 1}, {month: 2}, {month: 4}, {month: 6}];
let min = Math.min.apply(Math, myArray.map(o => o.month));
let max = Math.max.apply(Math, myArray.map(o => o.month));

const createArray = (i) => {
  let fooArray = [];
  for (let index = 1; index <= i; index++) {
      fooArray.push({month: index})
  }
  return fooArray;
}

console.log(createArray(max));
```